# Different date accessors in same Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, accessor

I have this, and it works nicely to give me UK-formatted dates:

```
protected $dateFormat = 'd-m-Y';
protected $dates = ['purchased', 'warranty_expires', 'scrapped_on', 'location_date', 'user_date'];
```

However, I also have created and modified (not the standard Laravel ones, but my own) that are Timestamps, not dates. How can I automate the formatting of those two fields when they are retrieved, to something like 'd-m-Y H:i:s' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Carbon library

```
public function getFormattedPurchasedAttribute($date)
{
   return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
}
```

You have to use carbon class. Write this line in the top where all namespace are used.

```
use Carbon;
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't use `$dateFormat` attribute because it changes format for all dates fields. What I would do is creating custom accessors to get formatted fields for example:

```
public function getFormattedPurchasedAttribute($value) {
  return $this->asDateTime($value)->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
}
```

so you can now use `$model-formatted_purchased` to get `purchased` field formatted in way you want

Comment: I get `Call to a member function format() on string` with this.

Comment: @daninthemix Please look at modified answer

Comment: I now get `InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425:
The separation symbol could not be found
Trailing data`. Also note that I don't always instantiate the model before using it, so `$this` might not work here.